# Need help and suggestion to integrate android app with my online room booking website

Tags: android

I have a online room booking website whose backend is written in ASP.NET..I wanted to create an android app which will be completely attached with the backend of my website..In my android app I want existing users to login and new users to sign up and then they can book rooms according to availability...So please kindly suggest me the requirement on how to start this project..I am clueless..My website is mobile responsive too..my expectation is great user experience.MY BIGGEST PROBLEM IS...HOW WILL I CONNECT MY APP WITH THE BACKEND SERVER....please suggest me or provide a reference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're web designer and don't know anything about developing mobile application in android/iOS then you should probably try **phonegap**

You can reuse your website code for Android/iOS application so you do not need to worry about back-end server connectivity or anything else. You just need to make sure that your web UI is mobile responsive. So it's better to use bootstrap/jQuery mobile.It will exactly work in mobile as it's working on web UI right now. Refer [phonegap doc](http://phonegap.com/) for more information.

Comment: What are the other alternatives to phonegap ? Can I create a REST API and fetch the data from the server ?

Comment: Yes , you can create REST API and fetch data from the server. But as I said if you're inexperienced in mobile development than you should go with phonegap. You do not need any extra efforts for this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate what are the most important functionalities of your room booking website. Create a list with each one and classify it.

After you do that, create prototypes of screen or create forms for your users asking what are the best features to include in the app.

I recommended you take a look in the [Android Material Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html). This will help you to achieve great user experience.

Comment: How to integrate the app with the backend server...that is the main trouble for me...

Comment: There are lot's of ways to do that. For sure, you will need to use HTTP libraries to achieve it

Comment: Do I need to create a REST API for that ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a REST API

Comment: Thanks a lot..how to do user authentication using REST API